# how to fit random vector into list of vectors python

Tags: python, vector

say I have the following list of vectors

```
vectors=[(10,0),(-10,0),(0,10),(0,-10)]
```

and I have the following random vector:

```
vector=(200,-300)
```

how can I get the vector from the list that is the most similar to the vector that I am inputting in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use scipy.spatial to find nearest neighbor.

Eg:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import spatial

vectors = np.array([(10, 0), (-10, 0), (0, 10), (0, -10)])
tree = spatial.KDTree(vectors)

vector = np.array([200, -300])

distance, i = tree.query(vector)

nearest = vectors[i]
```

Comment: Depending on OP's input size, the KDTree could be overkill or actually the optimization they need. Care to elaborate a bit more in your answer what it does?

Comment: this works completely thank you

Comment: I agree, it is a nice solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

First you need to define similarity between the vectors and your random vector (let's call it reference). Then you can use python's `min()` function to obtain the closest vector.

In this example I will use the squared Euclidean distance between both tuple members:

```
vectors = [(10,0), (-10,0), (0,10), (0,-10)]
reference = (200, -300)

def distance_to_ref(x):
   return (x[0] - ref[0])**2 + (x[1] - ref[1])**2

closest = min(map(distance_to_ref, vectors))
```

Instead of `map` function, people like to use the list comprehension:

```
closest = min([distance_to_ref(v) for v in vectors))
```

Likewise, instead of my native implementation of squared Euclidean distance you can plug in a more generic implementation from a library or write something completely different.